# HTTPS redirect to a folder not working

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config, iis-7.5, http-redirect

I just installed https certificate and am having a hard time setting up redirect.
I tried using HTTP Redirect in IIS (7.5) but can't get it to work in IE and in FF and Chrome once I pass the initial login page, I get "Too many redirect" error.
I also tried URL Rewrite but it was total failure so i reverted to HTTP Redirect.

Users used to access the site using "http://example.com/internal". Now, i want to redirect this to "https://internal.example.com/internal" and can't get it to work. I would much prefer not to use the last "internal" in the URL, if possible (the Common Name I used when requesting CSR was internal.example.com).

In HTTP redirect, I set "Redirect requests to this destination" to "https://internal.example.com/internal/default.aspx" and set "Redirect behavior" to "Only redirect requests to content in this directory" with Status Code 301 (Permanent).

Web site has an "internal" folder that contains the .Net application files and requires form authentication. The files in root folder are open to all (i.e. www.example.com is open to all).

Any help you can provide setting this up is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I updated web.config and added some URL Rewrite rule but still not quite there.
In IE, when I type example.com/internal it goes to https://internal.example.com but not http://internal.example.com/internal.
In Chrome, it doesn't go to https, stays in http and shows "Not secure".

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to internal" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="internal.example.com to sub folder internal" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^internal\.example\.com$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/internal($|/)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The first rule is to just let http://example.com go through; the second is to redirect http://example.com/internal to https://internal.example.com/internal.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Authentication applet in IIS. it should allow anonymous auth.

Comment: Thanks. I had "Basic Authentication" selected in addition to "Form Authentication" and it wasn't allowing me to enable Anonymous Auth. I disabled Basic and enabled Anonymous, but no change. I just updated the question with some addition info about web.config  modification.

Comment: I decided to ditch both URL Rewrite and HTTP Redirect and add a redirection statement using Response.Redirect on Page_Init of Default.aspx.cs if Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] and Request.ServerVariables["PATH_INFO"] satisfied my conditions for redirection. Works fine in all browsers.

Comment: I have a similar setup on a project, all I need to do was setup anonymous auth, disable all other authentication, then put a redirect on all port 80 traffic to 443 using aweb config rewrite.

Comment: I did't use URL rewrite, it was not working correctly for me and I just updated the web site's default.aspx.cs to do the redirection. I thik if you use the second part of my URL rewrite and get rid of 2n and 3rd input conditions, it should work for you.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me, I have mine working as required using a rewrite rule.